# Sublime Text package that shows git commit author and text inside the file on line cursor

Tags: sublimetext3

I have seen in Sublime Text 3 a way to show git author commit and text after you place the cursor on line of code (screen shot below). Which package do I need to install?

[image]

Comment: You're asking us to find or recommend packages for you, which is off-topic. Instead, you need to do the research, try things, pick one, work with it, then, when you have a problem ask a specific question about that particular problem.

Comment: I always do the reaserch first prior asking a question on SO.

Comment: See "[ask]", and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)". Recommendation requests for off-site resources are off-topic. You could use Sublime's package manager which makes it easy to discover packages, and a simple search in the repository for "git" brings up choices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That functionality is provided by the [GitGutter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) package; in particular it's controlled by the `show_line_annotation` setting:

```
    // (ST3, Build 3124+ only)
    // Display a phantom text at the end of the active line with information
    // about who changed it using the output of `git blame`.
    //   "auto"  -- show line annotation if word wrap is disabled (default)
    //   "true"  -- always show line annotation
    //   "false" -- never show line annotation
    "show_line_annotation": "auto",
```

Shown above is the default value, which enables it as long as word wrap is turned off. If you use word wrap then you need to modify the setting to `true` in your custom settings in order to see it in action.

Comment: Thanx, that's what I meant.

Comment: I saw the same functionality in `phpstorm2020.1` by adding a plugin called `git toolbox` and wanted to achieve the same thing in sublime text build 4126.